# We shouldn't use [identification-request] on questions that aren't really identification requests

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

Eric's post a few days ago about identification requests contains a problematic paragraph:

> First, let it be clear that I am talking about *identifying an anime or manga from one or more images*. Some questions, while tagged with [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request), are **not** identifying anime or manga, but rather elements of a series. ([This question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4239/274) is one example.)

The fact that Eric has to specify that he is talking about *one* kind of [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) question but not *the other* kind of identification-request question strongly suggests that we are using the tag to refer to too many different kinds of things.

Let's take a look at the tag wiki excerpt:

> For questions which ask about the identification of an anime/manga/character using a description; specific elements (like a character or song); or screenshots.

There are two **entirely** different types of questions here. First, we have questions in which the user does not know the name of the anime/manga/franchise they are looking for. This is the "conventional" sort of identification request, and I think it is uncontroversial that we should tag them with [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request).

But on the other hand, this tag is also being used for questions where the user knows what franchise they're in and seeks to identify a "specific element". For example:

- [What is the song from Naruto Shippuden episode 48 - Bonds at 3:10?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20286/1908)
- [What's the name of the music played during the final battle of Tokyo Ghoul √A episode 9?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20217/1908)
- [Who is the general depicted in the ending of Oda Nobuna no Yabou?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19464/1908)
- [Who is the character sporting a mohican whom Onizuka is parodying?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19239/1908)

I see why people are tagging these questions with [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) - the asker wants something "identified", right? But this is a dangerous line of thinking. Should we tag [Is Nadia voluntarily inspired by Castle in the Sky?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20229/1908) with [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) because the asker wants to "identify" the connection between Nadia and Castle in the Sky? What about [The Kamisama Hajimemashita anime covers the manga up to what chapter?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20561/1908) - doesn't the asker want to "identify" the chapter at which the anime ends? No, of course we shouldn't.

This latter type of question is a completely different beast than the "conventional" identification request. Indeed, they even require different skillsets to answer - to answer a "conventional" identification request, you need to be good at Googling and mind-reading. Whereas, to answer a question like [What is the context of this reference to Chrollo Lucilfer in Inou Battle manga chapter 1?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/18615/1908), you need to know things about Hunter x Hunter and Inou Battle.

As such, I move to amend the tag wiki excerpt for [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) to read something like this:

> For questions in which you want to find the name of an anime, manga, or other work based on screenshots/recollections/etc.

Then, we ought to remove [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) from all the places where it's inappropriately used (probably somewhere over half of these: http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/295881).

---

Here is another example: [Who is the creator of the manga Yu Yu Hakusho?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21027/1908). It was not tagged with [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request). But it asks for the author (a tangible entity) to be *identified*. Should we tag this with [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request)? If one wishes to be consistent with the tagging decisions I describe above, I would think so. (For the purposes of this discussion, ignore the fact that the question sucks.)

---

tl;dr Let's stop using [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) on things that aren't "conventional" identification requests.

Comment: I mostly expect [identification-request] to be used on questions that identify tangible things (whether in-universe or out-of-universe). An anime, manga, or sound track is tangible, as is a specific character within a series. This was [touched upon in an earlier meta post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/545/274).

Comment: @キルア Okay, sure, that's how we've been doing it, but why? What value do we get by tagging questions like "what is this song from this show called?" with [identification-request]? From the perspective of "tags should help experts find questions they can answer", does it make sense to send the experts on googling and mindreading to answer questions on in-universe things?

Comment: I agree, if we already know the work, there's no need for id-req to be on it. we get enough flak as it is for that tag, lets just keep it for id-ing works we don't know.

Comment: @senshin I tend to agree, though I feel like those questions need something. I don't think every expert in FMA knows the OST as well, for example, so keeping *just* that tag on there is perhaps undesirable. I think other sites use [*-identification] (where * is music, game, movie, etc.) but I don't think we can change that at this point. To me, a question asking for an OST track needs more than just [series][music].

Comment: There is also the case of identifying reference. Is it correct to assume that this meta post doesn't touch on this type of questions?

Comment: @キルア My position seems to be the opposite of yours - I don't think we should even use [music] on questions like that (though I don't feel very strongly about this). Consider the consequences of this if we were to carry this through more thoroughly - should we use [plot] on questions about plot of FMA, or [characters] on questions about characters in FMA? If we do, we end up with a tagging scheme like at Movies.SE. Now, one thing that would work here, in my opinion, would be to tag questions with something like [fma][fma-music], just like on SO we would tag questions with, say, (...)

Comment: (...) [android][android-resources], or whatever. The problem, of course, is that none of these "subsidiary" tags would have enough questions to be worthwhile on a site our size. But the current paradigm of [fma][music] is analogous to [android][resources], which is of course frowned upon on SO because people are typically not experts on "resources" but rather on resources in the context of a particular system/framework/etc. Expanding that to [fma][music][id-request] is like... I don't know, [android][resources][programming] or something.

Comment: @senshin That's part of what makes this so hard (our size, that is). Ideally we *would* have [fma-music] tags. But at the same time, I think it's rare that an expert solely in [fma] would be able to answer all OST questions, while some would be able to. I can see both sides of this, though, and the problem is that I'm not sure either one works perfectly.

Answer (score -3):

You bring up a very good point. But comments have also brought up a good point in that it is, nonetheless, the identification of *something*.

I therefore propose a new tag — or better: a series of tags — to be implemented which signifies you know the series but you want to know details.

If it's a single tag, something along the lines of [content-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-identification), [element-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/element-identification) or similar.

If a series is preferred, it is easier to name them:

- [character-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-identification)
- [music-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-identification)
- [other-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/other-identification)
- etc.

Of course it is a lot of work to skim through the 1250 questions tagged with [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) at the time of posting this suggestion to potentially retag them, but I think it's possible.

Maybe in that context, [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) might also be migrated into [series-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series-identification), [manga-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-identification) or similar. It would stop people using [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production) when they want an anime identified, because when they type `manga` the 'correct' tag would be suggested.

Comment: "It would stop people using [anime-production] when they want an anime identified" - for this, we actually do already have [anime-identification] [synonymed to \[identification-request\]](http://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/synonyms)

Comment: I don't see why this is being downvoted as it's essentially the solution to the problem (if it is a problem)